# PowerBI - How to See All Pages Being Linked to

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have a page called "Courses".

On this page, I select certain filters.

1. When I log into https://app.powerbi.com and select the filters, there is a Tab on the left that says "Courses" and a table appears after selecting the filters.
2. When I open up the Power BI Desktop file and select filters on the "Courses" tab, I don't see the same table.

How can I see how what filters are linked to what tables so that when I go to Power BI Desktop, I can select the same filters and see the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out, the image was connected to a Bookmark.

> With bookmarks in Power BI Desktop, you capture the currently
> configured view of a report page, including filtering and the state of
> visuals. Later, you can go back to that state by selecting the saved
> bookmark.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks